# how can i give access to a particular user to create quotes even though he is not the opportunity owner?

Tags: administration

Is there a way we can allow one particular user or users of particular profile to create a quote even though they are not owners of the opportunity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OWD of Quote is 'Controlled by parent', so the ownership depends on the Opportunity record. Even if we assign Modify All permission on the Quote object of a specific profile it will not work. It will throw **Insufficient Privileges** during creation of Quote record under Opportunity.

**Workaround**

1. ***Enable Team Selling*** at your Salesforce org. To do this navigate to

Set up->Opportunity Team setting and select the checkbox.

2. Add Opportunity Team related list in the Opportunity Page Layout.
3. Now select the Opportunity for which you want to create the quote.
4. Add the user (other than Opportunity owner for which you want to create quote) in the Opportunity Team and provide Read-Write access
5. Now you can create Quote record peacefully.

(user should have at-least Create/Edit permission on Quote object in the profile)

**Automation**

You can also automate this in Opportunity trigger and add the team member with 'Edit' access.

```
OpportunityTeamMember member = new OpportunityTeamMember();  
member.OpportunityId = SomeOpp.Id;  
member.UserId = SomeUser.Id;  
member.TeamMemberRole = 'Sales Rep';

insert member;


List<OpportunityShare> shares = [select Id, OpportunityAccessLevel, RowCause from OpportunityShare where OpportunityId IN :SomeSetOfOpptyIds and RowCause = 'Team'];`
for (OpportunityShare share : shares){
share.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Edit';
}
update shares;
```

Comment: Would this mean that we would need to add the user to the team for each opportunity.  Can we do a trigger to automate this. I need one user who is sales manager to have access to create quotes for opps

Comment: You can automate this

Comment: @Prady   Updated my answer with automation and if it helps then mark

Comment: Thanks @santanuboral . I didn't expect the code for the automation. This is of great help